# Symfony nested constraints don't work properly

Tags: php, symfony, validation, constraints

I came across a strange problem with Symfony validation.
Seems that "nested" constraints don't work properly.

For example, I create a string variable $data which needs to be validated.

```
$data = 'string';
$constraint = new Assert\Type('integer');
$violations = $validator->validate($data, $constraint);
self::assertTrue($violations->count() > 0);
```

In this case it works properly. We pass the string variable to the constraint which allows only integer. But if I create "nested" constraint the test won't pass.

```
$data = 'string';
$constraint = new Assert\Required([
    new Assert\Type('integer'),
]);
$violations = $validator->validate($data, $constraint);
self::assertTrue($violations->count() > 0);
```

In this case the test is failed. The validator doesn't find any violations.

Is it a bug? Or do I do something wrong?

Comment: Is there a `Assert\Required` constraint at all? What are you trying to achieve here? It makes no sense to me, having a "Required" surrounding a "Type". I mean, every constraint is kinda "required", and having an integer implicts a non-null value

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-4-nested-validation-attributes) you could group/nest constraints using *Validation Attributes*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Jonathan.
Actually I don't need Required constraint, just wanted to have multiple constraints for one value. I saw an example that they use Required or Optional to group multiple constraints. Now I can see from your documentation link that I can use just an array with constraints. So it was wrong constraint usage by me.

Comment: Glad it helped. I'll add it as an answer for others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want your data to be not empty (required) and to be a number:

```php
$data = 'string';

$validator = Validation::createValidator();
$violations = $validator->validate($data, [
    new NotBlank(),
    new Type(['integer'),
]);
```

see https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/validator.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no `Assert\Required` constraint.

Since Symfony 5.4 you can use **Attributes** to combine constraints:

```php
#[Assert\All([
    new Assert\NotNull(),
    new Assert\Range(min: 3),
])]
```

or

```php
#[Assert\Collection(
    fields: [
        'foo' => [
            new Assert\NotNull(),
            new Assert\Range(min: 3),
        ],
        'bar' => new Assert\Range(min: 5),
        'baz' => new Assert\Required([new Assert\Email()]),
    ]
)]
```

https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-4-nested-validation-attributes

Comment: I think those constraints are applied to an array (or Traversable object) based on the doc.